# Find all packages that depend on a specific one

Tags: r, dependencies, package

Is it possible to scan all the packages on CRAN in order to find all those that are dependent on a specific package?

I have found out how to do that but only on the packages I have installed and that is not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can do (with a package randomly picked from CRAN):

```
tools::package_dependencies(package = "ABHgenotypeR")

$ABHgenotypeR
[1] "ggplot2"  "reshape2" "utils"
```

If you need the reverse dependencies, you can do:

```
tools::package_dependencies(package = "ABHgenotypeR",
                            reverse = TRUE)

$ABHgenotypeR
character(0)
```

From documentation:

> For given packages which are not found in the db, NULL entries are
>   returned, as opposed to character(0) entries which indicate no
>   dependencies.

And you can do it for multiple packages simultaneously:

```
packages <- c("ABHgenotypeR", "accelerometry", "ACNE")
tools::package_dependencies(package = packages)

$ABHgenotypeR
[1] "ggplot2"  "reshape2" "utils"   

$accelerometry
[1] "Rcpp"   "dvmisc"

$ACNE
[1] "aroma.affymetrix" "MASS"             "R.methodsS3"      "R.oo"             "R.utils"         
[6] "matrixStats"      "R.filesets"       "aroma.core"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about doing it programmatically, the easiest way is to look at the corresponding CRAN web page (i.e. `https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=PKGNAME`) and look at the "Reverse depends:", "Reverse imports:", and "Reverse suggests:" sections.